# getting a attribute value in a directive in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive

```
 configModule.directive('iMemoryDiv',function () {

return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/memoryDiv.html',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {              
            scope.iObj = scope.$parent[attrs.bIObject];     
            if(angular.isDefined(scope.iObj)){                    
                getSummary(scope.iObj);
            }
            function getSummary(iObj){
            }


        }
    };
}
```

);

and I am calling it from html by passing an object attribute

```
 <i-memory-div b-i-object="app"></i-memory-div> //here app is declared in a respective controller
```

but, here directive is getting loaded before the controller where value for 'app' is getting assigned.So `scope.iObj = scope.$parent[attrs.bIObject]` is always giving me undefined.
How can make directive load after the app value is getting assigned ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it easier doing it this way:

```
configModule.directive('iMemoryDiv',function () {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        'bIObject': '=',
        'getParentObject': '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/memoryDiv.html',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('bIObject', function(newValue) {
            if(angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
               getSummary(scope.getParentObject({name: newValue}));
            }
        });
        function getSummary(iObj){
        }
    }
};
}
```

Or do you need more from the parent scope??

Answer (score 0):

You could give your directive an isolated scope and add bIObject as a scope property:

```
scope: {
            bIObject: '=',
        },
```

you could then put your code in the controller: rather than link:

Answer (score 0):

Use **$observe** service in link function,like this

```
if(attrs. bIObject) {
   attrs.$observe('bIObject', function(value) {
   console.log(value);
   })
}
```

Comment: Make BIObject as biObject..as Edited above(now)... and also in the html recheck the closing tag,It is wrongly spelt as </instance-memory-div> instead of </i-memory-div>